# Write requests are only supported on contained entities, Microsoft Graph API, Groups, PowerShell

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I try to run the PS script, but receive an error "Write requests are only supported on contained entities", any ideas?

API Application permission access granted: GroupMember.ReadWrite.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All;
Access token well received;

PS:

```
function AddB2BToDisabledGroup (){
    param(
        [string]$AccessToken
    )

$B2BAddToDisabledGroupHeaders = @{Authorization = "Bearer $AccessToken"}
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupID/members/$ref"

$Body = @"
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/$b2buserID"
}
"@
$addtogroupres = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $B2BAddToDisabledGroupHeaders -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/json' -ErrorAction Stop
$addtogroupres.status
}
```

Using the Tenant Admin account, using Graph Explorer, using the same group and user ID, POST works fine.
Tested also with:
"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/**users**/$b2buserID"